# pass a variable in url to resource callback function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

```
app.factory('Greeter', ['$resource',function($resource){
  return $resource(
    'http://123.com/processor.php?'+'myvar=1066',
    {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},
    {
      query: {method:'GET',isArray:true}
    });
}]);
```

I tried to pass a simple static variable into a php file to get call back value yet, its seem not pass correctly with the way I use above. Since the chrome inspector shows that

```
Query String Parametersview parsed
callback=JSON_CALLBACK
```

I wonder what is the right way to do it?

Thank You

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent **JSONP** https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
app.factory('Greeter', ['$resource',function($resource){
  return $resource(
    'http://123.com/processor.php',
    {

          myvar: 1066,
          callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
    },
    {
      query: {method:'GET',isArray:true}
    });
}]);
```

Now you should get

```
http://123.com/processor.php?myvar=1066&callback=JSON_CALLBACK
```

after doing the following

```
Greeter.query()
```

or

```
http://123.com/processor.php?myvar=1066&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&myvar2=77777
```

by doing this

```
Greeter.query({myvar2: 77777});
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked well : D

Comment: Would you mind to show me how to reference the input in this case? Because the input field attribute as 'name' seem can not be reference correctly. I always got undefined value when I do that. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you are trying to use this field to pass to the query. You have to use <input ng-model="criteria.name" type="text"> and assuming you have a controller up there somewhere. You can do Greeter.query({ name: $scope.criteria.name}). If my assumptions are not correct I suggest you open a new question and perhaps post some plnkr/jsfiddle for quick working solution/answer.

Comment: I did almost just that, but seem not really work the way  it should be.. here is a new post about it, please feel free check it out :) appreciated! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083305/pass-a-input-field-value-into-angularjs-resource-undefined-and-error-shows-unkn