# Pass a input field value into angularjs $resource undefined and error shows unknown scope provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

```
 <script src="/library/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angularjs.js"></script>
<script src="/library/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/library/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script>
var app= angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);
app.factory('Greeter', ['$scope' , '$resource',function($scope,$resource){
  return $resource(
    'http://adam.shopkeeper.tekserve.com/awh/ngresource/processor.php',
    {
      myvar:$scope.inputName,
      callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'

    },
    {
      query: {method:'GET',isArray:true}
    });
}]);

app
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Greeter',
  function($scope,Greeter){
  /*alert("yes");*/
  $scope.greet = function(){
    //alert("greetttt");
    alert("before greeeter"+$scope.inputName);
    Greeter.query({inputName:$scope.inputName}, function(response){
      alert(response[0].myCodeId);
      $scope.output=response[0].myCodeId;
    });
  };
}]);
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Your name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="inputName" name="myInput" value="World"/>
    <button ng-click="greet()">greet</button>

  
  <div>
  Test Output Here

    {{output}}

  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The php file expect to return a single array item (i.e. item[0]), But that was not the problem. Because the $scope seems is not recognized for the inputName field, which I made it a model (though I am not sure if its the right thing to do).
The error message will show below:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- Greeter
```

I wonder where do I get it wrong?

Comment: Remove `$scope` dependency from your factory. You can't access to controller $scope from the factory (only to the `$rootScope`)

Comment: @Umidbek Karimov I guess the way I do it has created a seperated scope inside controller itself?

Comment: I am not sure then how could I reference the inputName model inside the factory in this case?

Comment: Controller has created own `$scope`, but factory doesn't need this scope, you can pass any parameter to the `$provider` from your controller (even `$scope`), but can't get access to controller variables from factory.

Comment: @Umidbek Karimov I updated the code, but new error emerged, as I expected, trouble on recognize the value of inputName. Where is the mistake?

Comment: any one? o.O hum... do any of you need any more info to resolve this? I am willing to provide! Thank you all!

Comment: This question appears to have attracted two answers. One was written before the major question rewrite, and one was written afterwards. I have thus rolled the question back to the last good state before the rewrite. I will ask mods to delete the invalidated answer, since it is smaller and not the accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/CKgWrson3IbMugRKdX5p?p=preview

A few problems that I fixed that others pointed out in the comment.

Remove $scope from factory. Here you are getting a generic $scope object but not the actual scope. You will get that in the controller.
When you call angular resource with query() the first argument is already the param. But you can specify the common params like you did before.

```
function($resource) {
  return $resource('mocked-resource.json', {
    callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
  }, {
    query: {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: true
    }
  });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wonder if I want the url dynamically respond to the $resource callback (i.e. return result into a page if I type in abc.com/log.php?var=1), should I use it to combine with ngRoute module? or just ngRoute module is enough? Do you know any similar exmaple or demostration on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Chen I am not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish but I am thinking that you want to change part of your page on that response. Changing part of the page can be done in various ways - perhaps you open a new question or go through ANgularJS docs...you can achieve that using ng-switch, ng-if, ng-view (routes) etc. Use the simplest solution but put down your uses cases on table for best decision.